# Change Folklore.org account password

Tags: passwords

I have an account on [Folklore](http://folklore.org), a popular website collecting stories about Apple's history.

I wish to change my account password, but unable to find any link to access my profile or settings. Neither do I find the forgot password link which is generally an alternative way to reset a password on many websites.

Can someone with experience using the site shed some light on how could it be achieved?

Comment: The only contact information I found on there was a bugs@folklore.org email address.  The site looks like it's circa 1997, so it's possible that their authentication procedure is very outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your response @jonsca. Because you mentioned that the site may have a outdated authentication procedure, should I be concerned about the security of my login information?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, the above was just idle speculation on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no **account management** feature on the website. So your options are:

- Create a new account
- Contact administrator at **bugs@folklore.org**

Comment: I always get a quick and relevant answer from you. Thanks a lot!